# NSURLConnection Not Returning Data

Tags: iphone, cocoa, nsurlconnection

I have a rather unusual issue here. The code below is running fine and the data is sending to the source fine, but none of the NSURLConnection triggers are returning anything. The only items being logged are in the function that the request is sent in. Any ideas?

```
    // code starts above here

    NSData *myRequestData = [ NSData dataWithBytes: [ requestString UTF8String ] length: [ requestString length ] ];
    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlPrefix]]; 
    [request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody: myRequestData];   
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
    NSURLResponse *resp = nil;
    NSError *err = nil;
    NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse: &resp error: &err];
    NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];

    if (!theConnection)
    {
        NSLog(@"Failed to submit request");
    }
    if(theConnection)
    {
        NSMutableData* receivedData=[[NSMutableData data] retain];
        NSLog(@"Created connection.");

        NSLog(@"--------- Request submitted ---------");
        NSLog(@"receivedData: %@", receivedData);
    }
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSLog(@"Received response: %@", response);
    NSLog(@"Received response, connection retain count is %d",[connection retainCount]);
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    NSLog(@"Connection received data, retain count: %d", [connection retainCount]);
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
    NSLog(@"finished connection retain count:  %d", [connection retainCount]);
}
```

Comment: What about -connection:willSendRequest:redirectResponse:? Also, you should always implement -connection:didFailWithError:.

Comment: Sorry, there is a connection:didFailWithError function but it's further down in my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request 
                                         returningResponse:&resp 
                                                     error:&err];
NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request 
                                                               delegate:self 
                                                       startImmediately:YES];
```

First you start a synchronous request and then you start the request *again* but than asynchronous. Makes no sense.

Try removing the first line.